# What is the easiest way to initialize mutliple instances and its properties in C#, when we could have hundreds of objects?

Tags: c#, initialization

Let's say I have a class, which has the following constructors:

```
TestClass();
TestClass(int payloadLength);
TestClass(param byte[] payload);
```

And, for my application, I need to create multiple objects of this class, all of them with different values. Let's say:

```
TestClass obj1 = new TestClass(0)
{
    id = 0x01;
    value = 0x25;
    name = "First Object"
};

byte[] obj2Payload = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x02 };

TestClass obj2 = new TestClass(obj2Payload)
{
    id = 0x02;
    value = 0x53;
    name = "Second Object"
};
```

The thing is, I need to initialize a lot of objects of this class. We could have hundreds of objects.

Is there an easy way to initialize them, like you could do in C/C++ with XMacros? Or something similar?

**Note:** For this example I used obj1 and obj2 as the name of the instances, but in the real application, the name of the instances should be significant.

Comment: The easy way (though likely not the fastest) would be to create a JSON file that contains your initiation information as an array of objects whose properties match the objects you want to create, and then deserialize the JSON into a collection of your objects

Comment: Another way would be to create a specialized collection that wraps a `List<TestClass>` and that has an `Add` method that takes as parameters, the data you want to use to populate the properties (you can have multiple override `Add` methods if you want) and then use *Collection Initialization* syntax https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers

Comment: *"like you could do in C/C++ with XMacros"* - there are no macros in C#. Can you show how does initialization in C/C++ looks like? I don't see a problem with your current approach (there are minor things like [naming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) and using auto-incremented id). What is *easier* means exactly? Are you aware about [T4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/design-time-code-generation-by-using-t4-text-templates)?

Comment: @Sinatr, I am aware that macros doesn't exist in C#. I mentioned C/C++ because I have good background. The following example is not instance initialization in C++, but is a good example of how you can initialize variables quickly using XMacros, and multiple variables could be updated only with one line:
https://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go - using *[Collection Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)* syntax.  It's a bit like something that's macro-driven, but isn't.

First create your TestClass class.  This is what I imagine you meant to include in your question (but didn't - it would have been nice for you to type it):

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private byte[] _payload;


    public TestClass()
    {
        _payload = new byte[0];
        Name = string.Empty;
    }

    public TestClass(int payloadLength)
    {
        _payload = new byte[payloadLength];
        Name = string.Empty;
    }

    public TestClass(byte[] payload)
    {
        _payload = payload;
        Name = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Then I create my purpose-built collection class.  Notice that it implements `IEnumerable` and has an `Add` method of the right signature (in fact, it has several overloaded Add methods). The IEnumerable implementations use simple `yield return` statements in the normal fashion:

```
public class TestCollection : IEnumerable<TestClass>, IEnumerable
{
    private readonly List<TestClass> _items = new List<TestClass>();

    public void Add(int id, int val, string name)
    {
        var item = new TestClass
        {
            Id = id,
            Value = val,
            Name = name,
        };
        _items.Add(item);
    }

    public void Add(int id, int val, string name, int payloadLength)
    {
        var item = new TestClass(payloadLength)
        {
            Id = id,
            Value = val,
            Name = name,
        };
        _items.Add(item);
    }

    public void Add(int id, int val, string name, params byte[] payload)
    {
        var item = new TestClass(payload)
        {
            Id = id,
            Value = val,
            Name = name,
        };
        _items.Add(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<TestClass> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var item in _items)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Each of those `Add` methods takes the parameters it's passed and uses them to create a `TestClass`.  Then it adds it to its private collection.

Finally, here's some code that creates the collection.  Note that the various *intializers* match the signatures of the `Add` methods.

```
var stuff = new TestCollection
{
    {0x01, 0x25, "First Object"},
    {0x01, 0x53, "Second Object"},
    {0x03, 0x42, "With Payload Length", 12},
    {0x04, 0xff, "With a Payload as an Array", new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4}},
    {0x05, 0xab, "With a Payload as a params Array", 1, 2, 3, 4},
};
```

The syntax is reminiscent of JSON syntax, but the parameters/properties are set by position, not name (so it requires less typing).  It's also much more efficient than parsing a text file at runtime.

Comment: @Helbirah: I threw this together quickly. Some notes: if ID should be autoincrementing, you can do that with a private static int (say `currentId`) within the TestClass class, and having each constructor do something like `Id = currentId++;`.  If you want to be able to use the Name property in a useful fashion, have TestCollection wrap a `Dictionary<string, TestClass>` (instead of just a List) and provide access to items by name.